# How does the R function arima() calculate its residuals?

Tags: r, arima, residuals

I am new to time series and I am trying to figure out exactly what does on beyond the scenes in R. Say I have the MA process:
$$y_t - \mu = a_t+\theta_1 a_{t-1} + \theta_2 a_{t-2}$$ where $a_t$ are i.i.d. standard normal. For concreteness let $\mu = 0$, $\theta_1 = 0.2$ and $\theta_2 = 0.5$. I have implemented a simulation of this process and fit an MA(2) model back on it:

```
set.seed(47)
n = 200

a = rnorm(n,0,1)
a0 = rnorm(1,0,1)
an1 = rnorm(1,0,1)

theta = c(0.2, 0.5)

y = NULL
y[1] = a[1] + theta[1]*a0 + theta[2]*an1
y[2] = a[2] + theta[1]*a[1] + theta[2]*a0
for (t in 3:n) {
  y[t] = a[t] + theta[1]*a[t-1] + theta[2]*a[t-2]
}

MAfit = arima(y,order = c(0,0,2))
```

Now, when I take the residuals from this arima() call, the first residual is 2.745251. However when I subtract $y(1)$ from the estimation of the mean produced by arima(), I get 3.122668. How is R computing this first residual then? The code I used for these respective calculations is:

```
residuals(MAfit)[1]        (returns 2.745251)
y[1] - coef(MAfit)[3]      (returns 3.122668)
```

My understanding is that for $t=1$, we have:
$$\hat{a}_1 = y_1 - \hat{\mu}$$
from rearranging my first equation and using only expected values for $a_0$ and $a_{-1}$. Where have I gone wrong? Thank you!

Please note I have the same problem using TS data given to me, so I don't think this is an issue with my MA(2) implementation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equation you expect does hold but only if the conditional sum-of-squares (CSS) estimator is used. The default in `arima()` is to use CSS only for the starting values and then carry out full maximum likelihood (ML) estimation to integrate over the starting values.

But the computations you expected can be obtained in the following way:

```
css <- arima(y, order = c(0, 0, 2), method = "CSS")
cf <- coef(css)
residuals(css)[1:3]
## [1]  3.1099177  1.0096719 -0.6039833
```

This only sets two starting values for the innovations to zero, i.e., assumes $a_0 = a_{-1} = 0$. All subsequent computations are done conditional on this:

```
a <- c(0, 0)
```

The iteration for the first three residuals can then be done by the following `for()` loop. (Note that the index of `a` always has to be shifted due to the starting values.)

```
for(i in 1:3) a[i + 2] <- y[i] - cf[3] - cf[1] * a[i + 1] - cf[2] * a[i]
a
## [1]  0.0000000  0.0000000  3.1099177  1.0096719 -0.6039833
```

So this replicates exactly what you expected. For the default ML estimation the situation is more complex because this integrates out the distribution of the starting values. See the references listed in `?arima` for more details. A good introductory textbook is also Cryer & Chan which covers this topic in Chapter 7.